# Can't access yii:app() properties

Tags: php, session, yii

Whenever I try to access `Yii::app()` properties, such as `user` or `session` The program finished and I get a `200 OK` response.
If I try to access any of the other properties everything is fine.  Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for that?

**EDIT**   (if it helps)

```
      'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
          ),

            'file'=>array(
                'class'=>'application.extensions.file.CFile',
            ),

         'cache'=>array( 
                        'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache', 
                    ),    
);
```

Comment: show code how you accessing

Comment: `$test = Yii::app()->session;` => Program finished with `200 OK`.    
    
`$test2 = Yii::app()->request;` => Everything is fine, continue to next line of code.

Comment: show code `protected/config/main.php` from `components`. Add to question

Comment: added it to the original post

Comment: user1908466 see answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `session` in `components` array:

```
'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
           'class' => 'application.components.WebUser',
           'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
         ),
         'session' => array(
             'class' => 'CHttpSession',
             'autoStart' => true,
         ),
        'file'=>array(
            'class'=>'application.extensions.file.CFile',
         ),
        'cache'=>array( 
             'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache', 
         ),    
);
```

Comment: ok it still doesn't work but at least now I'm getting something. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_name() in /var/www/yii-1.1.14/framework/web/CHttpSession.php on line 197"

Comment: @user1908466 try remove `'sessionName' => 'Site Session'`

Comment: @user1908466 do var_dump($_SESSION) & var_dump($_COOKIE) anywhere. What does return both ?

Comment: `$_SESSION` = NULL & `$_COOKIE` = array(0){}

Comment: back to the start again